# How can I achieve this warm, sunny, saturated effect in Photoshop?

Tags: reverse-engineering, effect

I have 2 photos: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSQa2.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crga4.jpg). I've been trying to achieve this effect for two months, but every time something is wrong. Help please. Maybe, some special plug-in is used for this processing? Especially, I am interested in amazing sharpness, lighting, sunny tone.

Comment: Where did the original photos come from?

Comment: Personally, I like the before a lot better then after.

Comment: That photo shows distinct signs of at least being influenced by Kevin Kubota. (And I wouldn't be at all surprised to learn that it used his actions/presets for LR and/or PS. They're nothing you can't create yourself, of course, but you trade money for time.) Have you watched his "Post Pro" series on YouTube? It starts here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HciuI39pbUs

Comment: Sharpness is not noticeably different. I wouldn't try to replicate the sharpness, look at contrast instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This reminds me a great deal of the filter "[Glamour Glow](http://www.niksoftware.com/cepnx/usa_img/new_filters/glamour_glow.html)" which is part of a filter pack by Nik Software called "[Color Efex Pro 4](http://www.niksoftware.com/colorefexpro/usa/index.php?)". They do have a free trial and this may be a good start to get the glow effect.

Answer (score 26):

- Increase the contrast - globally and additional local contrast in the trees and other areas
  (when you say amazing sharpness I think it's a big boost in contrast that you're noticing)
- Increase saturation
- Warm the image - you can see the greens have gone yellow
- Vignette
- In addtion, looks like they've applied some "glow" to the image. You can do this by duplicating the layer, blurring it at say 20-25 pixels, then setting the blend mode to overlay or soft light.  That will further boost saturation and contrast as well.

Comment: you're answer gave me much more ideas than most of the tutorials I've read so far...

Answer (score 4):

Try to increase the clarity and vibrance, which will give your image more *punch*